# Chrome does not perform conditional GET for images referred via css

Tags: html, google-chrome

My page has a div with background image. I want the browser to always check freshness of this image. HTTP headers on the image are -

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 30 Jun 2014 11:14:40 GMT
```

Background image is specified in css linked to the same HTML page.

When I perform a Ctrl+F5, chrome sends request and gets a 200 response. But, on next F5, chrome loads the image from cache and Status code is shown as 200 (from cache). No request is sent to the server. I verified this using chrome://net-internals.

If I specify the same background image using style attribute to the div element, on next F5, chrome sends a conditional GET request and may fetch the contents if server responds with code 200.

Also note that the same caching policy is applied on css (which specifies the image) as well. And chrome does send conditional GET for the css on next F5.

I could not find anything to suggest that this is expected/known behavior for chrome.

Firefox and IE both send conditional GET request irrespective of where I specify the background-image.